# I'm trying to find a way to mail the contents of a file with Python

Tags: python, email, mime

I'm trying to make a script which has to mail the result of a test to a receiving party in the body of the mail.

In file A I run some code which adds text to a .txt, and close with

```
logger.mail('Testresult ' + date)
```

This part calls for the following part of code, in a file called logger:

```
def mail(subject):
    note = open("logs/IguanaResult" + datum + ".txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    print("logs/IguanaResult" + datum + ".txt")
    message = note.read()
    mailing.mail(message, subject)
    note.close()
```

Which then calls for the last part of code, in a file called mailing, which should send the mail:

```
def mail(message, subject):
    date = date.today()
    date = date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

    # Open password
    h = open("open password file", "r")

    # Email, pass, and receiver
    email = h.readline().split('\n')[0]
    password = h.readline()
    send_to_email = 'dedacted'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email
    msg['To'] = send_to_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    try:
        # Attach the message to the MIMEMultipart object
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
        print("content:" + message)
    except Exception:
        print("Could not attach message to MIME")

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    text = msg.as_string() # You now need to convert the MIMEMultipart object to a string to send
    server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
    server.quit()
```

The e-mail gets sent, but it only has a title. There's no body.

I'm hoping StackOverflow can help me out, since's there's no error message...

Comment: `bytes` has a method `decode` to convert to `str`; `str` has a method `encode` to convert to `bytes`. Maybe you meant to use `str` instead of `bytes`?

Comment: What do you pass to the `mail` function as the `message` argument?

Comment: I don't see any explicit use of `bytes` here. I assume `message` to be a string. What about explicitly setting `MIMEText` encoding, like: `MIMEText(message, 'plain', 'utf-8')`?

Comment: @mkrieger1: that's the part where I try to convert the file at `logs/IguanaResult" + date + ".txt` to  the body of the email

Comment: @TimVisée I tried that, gave the following error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Comment: On this line `note = open("logs/IguanaResult" + date + ".txt", "r")` try changing it to `note = open("logs/IguanaResult" + date + ".txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: After changing that the error is gone, but now it sends an empty email @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim

Comment: Does traceback of ```AttributeError``` points to MIME module? Would be easier to figure out when you've decided not to reveal your full code that produce your issue -

Comment: @jupiterbjy there is no more error luckily, but also no e-mail content now ...

Answer (score 0):

Minimal working example - test if your data file works with this code.

Change `get_sender_credential` according to your taste, I've loaded from file to easily hide it away from scripts.

If you still see blank message out of this then you might need to do encoding works - as I'm not sure about details on your data. No need to explicitly pass `'plain'` to `MIMEText` as it's default value.

Do note: use of `with` statements are recommended for file operations, rather than opening and closing manually. It prevents you not closing file as you've done with file-like object `h` if that's full function definition.

Additionally, you don't need to put args in `split('\n')` as split automatically splits on line breaks and spaces.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart


def get_sender_credential():
    with open("id.txt", 'rt') as fp:
        return fp.read().split()  # just to hide my credential with convenience


def handshake_smtp(smtp_addr, sender, passwd) -> smtplib.SMTP:
    smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_addr, 587)
    smtp_server.ehlo()
    smtp_server.starttls()
    smtp_server.ehlo()
    smtp_server.login(sender, passwd)

    return smtp_server


def send_mail(file_dir, subject, from_, to, smtp_server: smtplib.SMTP):
    with open(file_dir, 'rt') as fp:
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg.attach(MIMEText(fp.read()))

    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = from_
    smtp_server.sendmail(from_, to, msg.as_string())
    smtp_server.quit()


smtp_address, sender_addr, sender_pass, recv_addr = get_sender_credential()

smtp_server_instance = handshake_smtp(smtp_address, sender_addr, sender_pass)
send_mail("some_data.txt", "hello world!", sender_addr, recv_addr, smtp_server_instance)
```

[image]

Comment: While this code works fine (thanks btw!), I found out that the problem I had was that I forgot to close a text file. Now I'm using with open for everything, works like a charm.